# Why are all of these images and text boxes all on top of one another?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is create two rows of with three images in each, and then have text with a background image overlay each one of those (which will eventually fade in or out depending on mouse hovering), but even though I've used `display: inline`, it seems like the images are behaving as if they are `display: block`. And I don't even know where the text boxes are chillin' at. If there's an easier way to do this to overlay that text over the image, do let me know as well. Thank you very much for helping!

Here is the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wzbzyn67/#&togetherjs=gKOMzi2PKb

Comment: there are several markup errors, a stray <h1> is wrapping your rows, also second row is inside first row, try position:relative and float:left

Comment: even jsfiddle marks this red ;) as long as this is full of errors you cant expect any css to work

Answer (score 1):

The divs containing the episode images are block by default, you have to make them inline or inline-block

```
.episodeImage{
     display:inline-block;
}
```

Check the fixed fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/wzbzyn67/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the .episodeimage to display:inline to the end of your css.

```
.episodeImage {
  display:inline;
}
```